# Apache Sedona - Query a Non-Rectangular Raster Mask Using Spark on Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, raster, apache-sedona

I'm referring to the [manual](https://sedona.apache.org/tutorial/sql/#run-spatial-queries) on how to query spatial data, but in my scenario, there is a pixel-wise *raster* dataset of climate data over 8000+ days.

---

In simple words, the query could look something like this:

*select temperature data for 5000 days for the defined amorphous region and aggregate the values using spark*

---

My questions are:

- Should all the pixels be converted into vector-like "points" to be applicable for masking operations?
- Can third dimension (time) be somehow added to the spatial index, or should *date* be just a regular column?

Grateful for any input!

Some visual representation:
[image]

Comment: Have you looked onto the Mosaic: https://github.com/databrickslabs/mosaic/ ?

Comment: @AlexOtt didn't know about it, Thanks!